# Get page previews in React-Native

Tags: react-native, cheerio, oembed

I was trying to let users see web page previews in react-native like the link previews seen on Facebook and other apps. I've done some research.

I've seen some library that provides the function for node, but it doesn't work for react-native (because the original cheerio.js doesn't work directly with react-native)

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

I've checked the oEmbed library too, but it doesn't seem to work either.

I was wondering what might be the good ways for getting web page previews

Answer (score 2):

Ended up writing a small library that does the job. Hopefully it's useful to some people

https://github.com/changey/react-native-page-previewer

Usage

```
import preview from 'react-native-page-previewer';

preview("http://www.google.com", function(err, data) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

sample return

```
{ url: 'https://www.google.com',
  loadFailed: false,
  title: 'Google',
  description: 'Search the world\'s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking for.',
  contentType: 'text/html',
  mediaType: 'website',
  images: [ 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png' ],
  videos: undefined,
  audios: undefined }
```

Comment: Hey, I've been trying to use your library, but when I try to preview google.com I get a unhandled promise rejection and any other page gives undefined data, any ideas?

Comment: @ospfranco There was a fix merged a while ago. Could you try again? thanks!